# PHP array_push() 2-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-push

```
   array_push($typedict[$current], "value");
```

Does not seem to do anything here, i output the associative array of arrays($typedict) but all of them are empty(array()). I print the current associative index out with echo to confirm that it is the correct one(it always is).

Since the print chelc at the end states "[name] => Array()" i have no clue what could be the problem as this indicates that they are indeed arrays and therefore could have stuff pushed in. Also the var $current as stated always have the correct content. at:

```
echo "current: ". $current;
```

full code:

```
 <?php
    $typedict = array();
    $xsdstring = file_get_contents("infile.xsd");

    $xsdstring = str_replace("xs:choice", "xs:sequence", $xsdstring);



    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML(mb_convert_encoding($xsdstring, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($xsdstring)));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
    $xpath->registerNamespace('vc', 'http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning');

    function outputFormat($indent, $elementDef)
    {
        echo "<div>" . $indent . $elementDef->getAttribute('name') 
        . " type:" . $elementDef->getAttribute('type') 
        . " min:" . $elementDef->getAttribute('minOccurs') 
        . " max:" . $elementDef->getAttribute('maxOccurs') 
        . "</div>\n";
    }

    function echoElements($indent = "", $elementDef, $evaluate, &$typedict)
    {
        global $doc, $xpath, $current;

        if($indent == "")
        {
            $attribute_name = $elementDef->getAttribute('name');
            $typedict[$attribute_name] = array();
            $current = $attribute_name;
        }else{
            echo "current: ". $current;
            $type = $elementDef->getAttribute('name');
            array_push($typedict[$current], "value");
            #$typedict[$current][0] = "value";
            print_r($typedict[$current]);
        }

        outputFormat($indent, $elementDef);
        $elementDefs = $xpath->evaluate($evaluate, $elementDef);
        foreach($elementDefs as $elementDef)
        {
            echoElements($indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $elementDef, $evaluate);
        }
    }


    $elementDefs = $xpath->evaluate("/xs:schema/xs:element");
    foreach($elementDefs as $elementDef)
    {
        echoElements("", $elementDef, "xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element", $typedict);
    }    

    $elementDefs = $xpath->evaluate("/xs:schema/xs:complexType");
    foreach($elementDefs as $elementDef)
    {
        echoElements("", $elementDef, "xs:sequence/xs:element", $typedict);
    }

    print_r($typedict);
    ?>
```

Comment: What is `$current`?

Comment: You can't assign a key with `array_push()` - it simply adds the item onto the end of the array.  If you want to use `$current` to assign a key, why not simply do `$typedict[$current] = 'your value';`?

Comment: Because it is not the "key" but the key of the destination array. $typedict["whatever"] is an array. the array where i want to push in "value".

i.e: (linebreak)
typedict["whatever"][0] (linebreak)
typedict["whatever"][1] (linebreak)
...

Comment: I do not try to assign a key, the keys are all fine i really want wto push value into $typedict["whatever"] which is an empty array. The print at the end confirms that it is still an empty array as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score -1):

$current **does** contain the correct value. As seen in the code i check it pretty much everytime it gets set. So im pretty confident about that part.

I do **not** want to change whatever is in $current as it behaves excactly as i want.

My goal is an array inside each entry of the associative array $typedict.
Example:

```
$typedict["whatever"][0] = "value";
$typedict["whatever"][1] = "value";
...
```

$current is the index of $typedict not any of it's contents. So in this case $current contains the string "whatever" and **not** "value". And this is how it should be.

Edit:
I think i figured out the problem. But i have no clue how this could happen and therefore can't fix it:
$typedict["whatever"] seems to be only visible inside the IF block since the last value is okay if chekcked inside the block.

I somehow need to declare the whole structure of $typedict as global. Not just the base array(the associative one) but alos all the arrays inside it. But i only get to know the keys later.

Edit2:

Definetly a visibilty problem:
changing:

```
global $doc, $xpath, $current;
```

to:

```
global $doc, $xpath, $current, $typedict;
```

solved it